# Get D3 Brush/React/Flux Working Together

Tags: d3.js, reactjs, flux

I am trying to get a D3 brush working in React. Currently, I can successfully control the brush programmatically. When the user presses buttons in my other React components, my Flux store updates the current position, which updates the associated position prop, which updates the extent of the brush. All works well.

However, I also want the user to be able to click and drag on the brush element itself to resize and move it. In my _handleBrushed() component, I tried calling actions that update position and extent values in my Flux Store which update the props that control brush position, but this is causing my D3 component to remount, flash, and the brush jumps around suddenly as I try to resize or drag.

I suspect this is related to a conflict in DOM control between React and D3, so I must be doing something wrong. Can anyone advise me on how I should be structuring my code so that the user can interact with the brush the way D3 intended, but I can also control the position of the brush programmatically via user clicking buttons?

Thanks for any help!

class NewLineChart extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this._chartComponents = this._chartComponents.bind(this);
    this._brushComponents = this._brushComponents.bind(this);
    this._initializeChart = this._initializeChart.bind(this);
    this._initializeBrusher = this._initializeBrusher.bind(this);
    this._updateChart = this._updateChart.bind(this);
}


componentDidMount() {
    console.log('component mounting');
    this._initializeChart();
    this._initializeBrusher();
};

componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('component is updating');
    this._updateChart();
};

_chartComponents() {
    const { width, height, all_data, position, shift } = this.props;

    const innerMargin = { top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 10 };

    const data_range = all_data.slice(position,position+shift);

    const points = data_range.map((d, i) => ({ x: i, y: d }));

    const x = d3.scale.linear().domain(d3.extent(points.map(d => d.x))).range([0, width - innerMargin.left - innerMargin.right]);
    const y = d3.scale.linear().domain(d3.extent(points.map(d => d.y))).range([height - innerMargin.top - innerMargin.bottom, 0]);

    const line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate('cardinal')
        .x(d => x(d.x))
        .y(d => y(d.y));

    return {
        width,
        height,
        x,
        y,
        line,
        points,
        innerMargin,
    };
};
_brushComponents() {
    const { width, height, all_data, position, shift } = this.props;

    const innerMargin = { top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10 };

    const points = all_data.map((d, i) => ({ x: i, y: d }));

    const x = d3.scale.linear().domain(d3.extent(points.map(d => d.x))).range([0, width - innerMargin.left - innerMargin.right]);
    const y = d3.scale.linear().domain(d3.extent(points.map(d => d.y))).range([height/3 - innerMargin.top - innerMargin.bottom, 0]);

    const line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate('cardinal')
        .x(d => x(d.x))
        .y(d => y(d.y));


    const brush = d3.svg.brush()
        .x(x)
        .on('brush', () => this._handleBrushed(brush));

    brush.extent([position, position+shift-1]);

    return {
        width,
        height,
        x,
        y,
        line,
        points,
        innerMargin,
        brush
    };

};


_handleBrushed(brush) {
    //below were attempts at calling actions that change my position and size props that control the brush
    //Actions.adjustBrushWindow(brush.extent()[0],3);
    //Actions.slide(1);
    console.log('brushed', brush.extent());

};

_initializeChart() {
    const { line, points, innerMargin, height} = this._chartComponents();

    // draw the initial
    const svg = d3.select(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.svg))
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'inner-chart')
        .attr('transform', `translate(${innerMargin.left} ${innerMargin.top})`);

    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .append('path')
            .datum(points)
            .attr('d', d => line(d));
};

_initializeBrusher() {
    const { line, points, innerMargin, brush, height} = this._brushComponents();

    const { all_data }  = this.props;
    const brush_points = all_data.map((d, i) => ({ x: i, y: d }));

    const brusher = d3.select(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.brusher))
    .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'inner-chart')
        .attr('transform', `translate(${innerMargin.left} ${innerMargin.top})`);

    brusher.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .append('path')
            .datum(brush_points)
            .attr('d', d => line(d));


    brusher.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x brush')
        .call(brush)
        .selectAll('rect')
            .attr('y', -6)
            .attr('height', height/3 + 7)
            .attr('fill', 'red');

    console.log('extent: ' + brush.extent());




};


_updateChart() {
    console.log('in updatechart. Position: ' + this.props.position);
    const { line, points} = this._chartComponents();
    const { brush } = this._brushComponents();

    const {position, shift, all_data} = this.props;

    // draw the initial
    const svg = d3.select(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.svg)).select('.inner-chart');
    const brusher = d3.select(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.brusher)).select('.inner-chart');


    svg.select('.line path')
        .datum(points)
        //.transition()
        .attr('d', d => line(d));


    brush(brusher.select('.brush'));
    //console.log('new extent: ' + brush.extent());

};

render() {
    const { width, height } = this.props;

    return (
        <div style={{paddingRight:70}}>
            <div >
                <svg width={width} height={height} ref='svg' />
            </div>
            <div style={{backgroundColor:'Ivory', borderRadius:15}}>
                <svg width={width} height={height/3} ref='brusher' />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

};